# Where is output of NSLog() written?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an iPhone app. Is output of `NSLog` written in a file in iPhone?
I am in situation that if I didn't write `NSLog`, my app would not work. I don't care it is written in my iMac. But I care if it is written in iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `NSLog()` outputs text to the console, which can be read by the users on their devices by downloading some Console-app. It is suggested that you don't use  `NSLog()` for anything else than error reporting in the finished products, but it's fine during testing.

Here is an approach you could do to make sure the NSLog's outputted are only being called in the finished app: http://joshhighland.com/blog/2010/04/10/dont-use-nslog-anymore/

Comment: Console.app is installed with OS X in /Applications/Utilities.

Comment: I mean on the iPhone/iPad. There are third-party applications on the App Store allowing you to read the console, which includes Apple's own logs and all of the app's.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but when you call NSLog, the output is shown in the lower right window. For example if I do:

[NSLog http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/791/screenshot20111209at827.png](http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/791/screenshot20111209at827.png)

The output will be:

[Output http://img857.imageshack.us/img857/3128/screenshot20111209at828.png](http://img857.imageshack.us/img857/3128/screenshot20111209at828.png)

Also, make sure to select the console view in Xcode

[Console View http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/791/screenshot20111209at827.png](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/791/screenshot20111209at827.png)

If you want to show some text in the app directly, I suggest using UILabel or UITextView :)
See ya,
NiCK

Answer (score 0):

Quite to the contrary, the log is written in the debugger, like so:

[image: Xcode 4 debugger]

You can access the debugger by clicking on the middle button in the right-most tab bar on the navigation bar of Xcode (the tab bar is titled "View").  Your logs will looks something like this:

**2011-12-09 Example[55409:40b] Log message**

...giving the date, application, and some other stuff before the log message.